# Why do some virtual instruments sound more realistic than others?

Tags: daw, vst, virtual-instrument

This may be somewhat subjective, though it may be verified by a breakdown of the audio. But it seems easy to find like drums and other percussion, bass guitar, piano, harpsichord, maybe harps and organs, and others that sound realistic. But then like many horns or string instruments don't sound realistic. What is the reason for this?

Comment: Note that all the ones you note as being less realistic have a component of expression *after* the note is started (breath, bow...)

Comment: Yeah that probably has something to do with it, good point.

Comment: Jaron Lanier writes in his excellent *You Are Not a Gadget* about knowing the guy who invented MIDI to get his keyboard synths to talk to each other. Keyboards are based on a particular on/off time with a given velocity, and so MIDI models this well, but it's bad at more expressive instruments (e.g. a violin sliding through pitches in a single stroke -- often replicated as multiple notes with suppressed attacks). But due to technology lock-in, MIDI became the standard for every instrument. This is the reason for the superiority of percussive virtual instruments as the answers below note.

Comment: Are you saying there may be better options than MIDI?

Comment: Add to your list of the difficult to sample the singing voice, with all the nuance of voice type, timbre, vowels, consonants---good luck!

Comment: "I'm more talking about for putting together music ... in a DAW" - the better option than MIDI is microphones, record players, and *you* sampling actual instruments. I can tell from down the block that it's fake drums, and that's the 'easy' one to do.

Comment: Good 4 u lol. Maybe there are tests somewhere to see if ppl can tell the difference.

Comment: @user14094230 Sadly, no. MIDI remains the only standard for virtual music notation. All non-percussive modelling has to be done by combining CCs. Of course, this has gotten pretty sophisticated. A VST can map a range of expressions to a few CCs. They also use keyswitches to do more significant jumps, e.g. EW Hollywood has like 20 KS'd articulations for their solo violin, because the alternative is to have lots of buttons and sliders for tension, note length (because otherwise the peak can't be known till later when you release the key), stroke direction, vibrato (unheard of on keyboard!), etc.

Comment: @LukeSawczak: To be fair there are alternatives such as [OSC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_Sound_Control) and even [MIDI 2.0](https://www.extremetech.com/computing/305502-after-37-years-midi-2-0-is-ready-for-prime-time), which may work better for some people in specific situations, but neither as anything like the broad support of MIDI, which is a big drawback.

Comment: @psmears Right, yeah. If you do a character count on my comment you'll see it's exactly 600 characters ... had to delete the word "universal" before "standard" to get it to fit :')

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Compressing 30 years of research into a couple of short paragraphs…

Non-percussive instruments are what's known in the trade as "an absolute b**ch to sample" because they can change over time, unlike a percussive instrument which has a relatively simple release phase after the initial impulse.

Some huge sample libraries use many many variations of each possible note & how it might be played. The user has to choose individual 'articulations' to persuade the ear that this is a natural progression.  This is often combined with a 'round robin' structure which will play a different sample of each note each time it's re-triggered, to prevent the 'machine gun' effect of every one being exactly the same.

The player can help this along by modulating volume/vibrato etc over time, though the sound will not change to fully express the actual sound of a violinist playing harder or adding ever-changing vibrato.

There's a niche manufacturer who took an entirely different approach. Rather than each note being one of a selection of pre-recorded samples, each instrument is built from tiny snippets of sound, which can morph one into the other *whilst the note is playing*. This then sits within a mathematical model of the physics of the instrument string/wind/body.
Here's a demo - [AudioModeling, SWAM](https://audiomodeling.com/video-swam-virtual-instruments-demonstration/)

One thing to note - the harder it is to make each of these, the more expensive it is ;)

Comment: That alternate approach sounds interesting, I guess it could automatically add some unique randomness to each note played.

Comment: It's always random, because it's calculated millisecond by millisecond. It'e never the same twice. You should be able to play the same part twice on two separate tracks & not hear them phasing.

Comment: Physical modelling has always been computationally expensive. I worked alongside the team that built the first ever physical modelling synth, in the early 90s. At the time, the sound design was done on the fastest computer generally available, the Sun Sparc. Every time a parameter was changed, it would take between 10 minutes & an hour to calculate the new sound. Computers have got a bit faster since - though they do still have to cut some corners to make the end result truly realtime.

Comment: I'm more talking about for putting together music with midi files in a DAW, but yeah live, that's more of a challenge.

Comment: No, this was to compute the models that the user would then be able to play live [or record the midi for]. The final product had several pre-built models in it [my guys had to actually *design* the models] - the end user didn't have to wait for it to be calculated, it was already done for them; just like now with the SWAM synthesis, the models are already finished, meaning there's plenty of CPU time to play it either live or to a midi track.

Comment: This was the synth - https://www.yamaha.com/en/about/innovation/collection/detail/2025/ At that time, while they were working on that, I was working on this - the first modelling amp, precursor to Line 6, Guitar Rig, Amplitube etc ;( https://gear-vault.com/yamaha-dg100-amplifier/

Comment: @Tetsujin Remember to put that into your book :P!

Comment: @Tom - I'm sure it sounds a lot more exciting in bite-sized chunks than it would in novel length. "That day, one of the guys changed a reed/embouchure parameter on a saxophone… then we all went for lunch til it had finished recalculating. Pizza @ Condotti as I recall." We got through a lot of pizza & beer that year, across three continents;))

Comment: Is the point of modeling amps generally to sound like more expensive amps?

Comment: To sound like **any** amp you could ever own, & by some clever hybridising, some that never existed. I've always been a fan, from the early days right to now. I still have a 20-year-old Variax & Line 6 'amp'. Between them the world's my oyster… or frankly, mollusc of my choice ;) The models made today are very very clever, but tbh, they reached the level of 'almost no-one can tell it's not real' 20 years ago.

Comment: Cool, can't say I get your oyster/mollusc joke lol

Comment: [The world is your oyster](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/21713/what-is-the-meaning-and-origin-of-the-common-phrase-the-world-is-your-oyster) originally Shakespeare, later expanded by the late, great Terry Pratchett to include any mollusc.

Comment: I thought Line 6 has their own recognizable house sound, similar to Nord Electro or Roland pianos. Not that it's a bad thing and it could well pass for the real thing in mix.

Comment: @ojs - they have their own 'house sound' amp models, but also all the usual suspects, Marshalls, Fenders, Vox, etc etc. They don't use the real names, but it's easy enough to figure out what they are [& the front panels give you even more clues,  the pic is a Vox, if you couldn't guess - https://i.stack.imgur.com/rE58d.png There are a bunch of interchangeable cabinets & you can change the mic type & position, plus other FX, comps, gates, stomp boxes, reverbs etc This is the one I have [In fact I have two, in case one ever breaks] - https://www.soundonsound.com/reviews/line-6-toneport-ux1-ux2

Comment: @Tetsujin I know that's the marketing pitch but in my experience the simulations from NeuralDSP, AxeFX or even Yamaha aren't nearly as recognizable as Line 6. It could be that Line 6 was one of the first to the game and others have more refined technology or that I've listened to too many shows where one guitarist had a POD but I'm quite sure the Line 6 sound is a thing.

Comment: @ojs - a Pod would likely be recognisable if the guitarist left the 'Air' speaker sim on when connected to an amp [meaning they never read the manual]. The UX fixed the speaker sim completely. I still have a Pod [somewhere] but haven't used it in 20 years. The 'Air' was a bit of a weird sound.

Answer (score 9):

Any instrument that is percussive (you play the note and then there's almost nothing more you can do with it except stop it) is fairly easy to synthesize.

Any instrument where the player forms the note during the whole time it's played (and maybe connects it to the next note) are much harder to recreate. It's possible to make notes more expressive by modulating various parameters of the sound (volume, pitch, timbre etc.) but it takes a lot more work.

Comment: And I hesitated to make my comment an answer, would never have fast enough!

Comment: I feel like there are some exceptions, but I feel like this answer is good for the fairly general question I asked.

Comment: Percussive instruments can be still hard to model, if you want to reproduce a large variety of articulations. But of course I agree, it adds another level of complexity, if the sound parameters change while the note is being sustained.

Answer (score 4):

Others have mentioned more general answers, I'll try to provide a comparison of  two real instruments.

You mentioned it was easier to find guitar samples, then it was to find stringed instruments (e.g. cello).

If we look at a solid body electric guitar, it's plucked and then the strings movement is measured by electrical signal through the pickups:
[image]

Although other parts of the guitar might also be vibrating, most the main part of the sound is coming from the pickups.

Therefore if wanted to build a guitar synth, we would have to model how the strings vibrates and just use that signal to create our audio.

Now instead if we have a bowed cello (which looks like this, and doesn't use a pickup)

[image]

we can see that sound is produced by the bow moving across the string (which is more complex than just plucking the string), which then vibrates a certain string, which then vibrates the entire body of the cello producing a rich tone which doesn't take any amplification to hear.

The rich tone also arises from chladni figures, which describe the way a thin plane vibrates at different frequencies so when you play a note, the front and back of the cello may vibrate in different ways:

[image]

(the white and black says how much each section vibrates)

So we can see that if we put the same effort into building a guitar synth as into a cello synth, we'll probably end up with a better sounding guitar synth as we'd need more effort to model the complexity arising from the cello.

So on average this is part of why string synths may not sound as realistic as guitar synths.

Comment: Cool, useful pics

Comment: Do people use a lot of synthesized electric guitar? Amp simulations are used a lot, but it seems that guitar is one of instruments that are most often recorded with a real instrument.

Comment: Bass guitar tends to sound nicer. Most guitars I've tried didn't sound great, but at least one company does make alright sounding guitars imho. In the demos online guitars often sound ok, but once you use them, making individual notes or chords, the quality differences become much more apparent. Single notes usually sound better than chords.

Comment: "You mentioned it was easier to find guitar samples, then it was to find stringed instruments" This is a very, very small nitpick, but technically, guitars are stringed instruments (so are pianos too, but...). But I know exactly what you mean by that and why you said it that way. So I'm probably making a big deal over nothing.

Comment: I did say bass guitar. Normal guitar is hit or miss. But then like violin, I don't think I've heard a realistic one. Note chords on bass guitar aren't as common.

Comment: *which is more complex than just plucking the string* - a recent question on physics.SE has some interesting discussion and diagrams: [How does a violin produce notes, microscopically?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/774869)